# Is $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2},\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{2}\right]=\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ for some $\alpha$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Is $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}, \frac{1 + \sqrt{13}}{2} \right] = \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ for some $\alpha$?

I tried some examples, it seems not but I am not sure.

Comment: Show the cases you have tried and then we can help.

Comment: What cases? Explain your thoughts! It helps us understand what you did not understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modulo $2$, $R = \Bbb Z[\frac {1+\sqrt 5}2, \frac {1+\sqrt {13}}2]$ becomes isomorphic to $\Bbb F_4^2$.

If $\alpha \in \Bbb F_4^2$, then its minimal polynomial over $\Bbb F_2$ is the lcm of the minimal polynomials of its components.
Since the only minimal polynomials you have acces to are $T,T+1$ and $T^2+T+1$, the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is at most $3$.
Then $\Bbb F_2[\alpha]$ has dimension at most $3$ over $\Bbb F_2$ and it cannot be all of $\Bbb F_4^2$.

This implies that $R \neq \Bbb Z[\alpha]$ for any $\alpha \in R$.

Comment: I'm confused by your answer. Do you mean $\Bbb F_4^2$ to mean $\Bbb F_{16}$ (as opposed to $\Bbb F_4\times\Bbb F_4$)? The notion of minimal polynomial of an element of a general ring is unfamiliar to me. I'm also not seeing how you're reasoning that the minimal polynomial is the gcd of the minimal polynomials of its components. Say for example, $\alpha = (0,1)$. Then the minimal polynomials of the components are $T$ and $T + 1$, respectively, and their GCD is $1$ which is not the minimal polynomial of anything. Could you clear up this point?

Comment: sorry, I meant lcm instead of gcd. 
$\Bbb F_4^2$ means the product $\Bbb F_4 \times \Bbb F_4$.  
You can think of $\alpha$ as its multiplication map on the resulting $\Bbb F_2$-vector space, then think about the minimal polynomial of the corresponding matrix.

Comment: LCM as opposed to GCD clears things up. Thanks!